# Swedish text not hyphenated

Tags: hyphenation

I'm using a [template for cover letters](https://sv.sharelatex.com/templates/cover-letters/moderncv-casual) together with the line `\usepackage[swedish]{babel}` in my preamble. But I've noticed that long words don't get hyphenated (as they should when using babel), and end up on the next row, leaving long blanks on the row before, which looks very ugly. Is there a way to fix this so that words do get hyphenated?

**Edit:** An example that generates such blanks:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\name{}{}
\begin{document}
\recipient{Recipient}{Company}
\date{\dateswedish\today}
\opening{}
\closing{}
\makelettertitle

Pojken tyckte, att han aldrig hade sett sin mor så fortfärdig. I ett nu var hon borta vid vägghyllan, tog ner Luthers postilla och lade den på bordet framme vid fönstret med dagens predikan uppslagen. Hon slog också upp i evengelieboken och lade den brevid postillan. Sist drog hon fram till bordet den stora länstolen, som blev köpt på auktionen i Vemmenhögs prästgård förra året, och där eljest ingen annan än far fick sitta.

Det var så, att mor ägde en stor tung, järnbeslagen ekkista, som ingen annan än hon själv fick öppna. Där förvarande mor allt det hon hade ärvt efter sin mor, och som hon var särskilt rädd om. Där lågo ett par gammaldags bondkvinnedräkter av rött kläde med kort liv och veckad kjol och pärlbesatt bröstsmäck. Där funnos stärkta, vita huvudklutar och stora, tunga flaggstångsknoppar och kedjor. Folk ville inte gå med sådant nu för tiden, och mor hade flera gånger tänkt på att göra sig av med de gamla sakerna, men så hade hon inte haft hjärta till det. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: An example, please?

Comment: @egreg: An example has been added.

Answer (score 3):

The text is typeset ragged right, so it's not hyphenated: the language is irrelevant.

Some remarks.

1. You're missing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` that's mandatory if you want correct hyphenation of Swedish.
2. If you want less raggedness allowing some hyphenation, you can use the package `ragged2e`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\name{}{}

\begin{document}
\recipient{Recipient}{Company}
\date{\dateswedish\today}
\opening{}
\closing{}
\makelettertitle

Pojken tyckte, att han aldrig hade sett sin mor så fortfärdig. I ett nu var hon borta vid vägghyllan, 
tog ner Luthers postilla och lade den på bordet framme vid fönstret med dagens predikan uppslagen. Hon 
slog också upp i evengelieboken och lade den brevid postillan. Sist drog hon fram till bordet den 
stora länstolen, som blev köpt på auktionen i Vemmenhögs prästgård förra året, och där eljest ingen 
annan än far fick sitta.

Det var så, att mor ägde en stor tung, järnbeslagen ekkista, som ingen annan än hon själv fick öppna. 
Där förvarande mor allt det hon hade ärvt efter sin mor, och som hon var särskilt rädd om. Där lågo 
ett par gammaldags bondkvinnedräkter av rött kläde med kort liv och veckad kjol och pärlbesatt 
bröstsmäck. Där funnos stärkta, vita huvudklutar och stora, tunga flaggstångsknoppar och kedjor. Folk 
ville inte gå med sådant nu för tiden, och mor hade flera gånger tänkt på att göra sig av med de gamla 
sakerna, men så hade hon inte haft hjärta till det.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The same text in the standard class `article`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\begin{document}

Pojken tyckte, att han aldrig hade sett sin mor så fortfärdig. I ett nu var hon borta vid vägghyllan, 
tog ner Luthers postilla och lade den på bordet framme vid fönstret med dagens predikan uppslagen. Hon 
slog också upp i evengelieboken och lade den brevid postillan. Sist drog hon fram till bordet den 
stora länstolen, som blev köpt på auktionen i Vemmenhögs prästgård förra året, och där eljest ingen 
annan än far fick sitta.

Det var så, att mor ägde en stor tung, järnbeslagen ekkista, som ingen annan än hon själv fick öppna. 
Där förvarande mor allt det hon hade ärvt efter sin mor, och som hon var särskilt rädd om. Där lågo 
ett par gammaldags bondkvinnedräkter av rött kläde med kort liv och veckad kjol och pärlbesatt 
bröstsmäck. Där funnos stärkta, vita huvudklutar och stora, tunga flaggstångsknoppar och kedjor. Folk 
ville inte gå med sådant nu för tiden, och mor hade flera gånger tänkt på att göra sig av med de gamla 
sakerna, men så hade hon inte haft hjärta till det.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, the hyphenation in the word `flaggstångsknoppar` would not be found because of the accented letter.